# error running Julia on Ubuntu 16.04 docker for host with GPU

Tags: docker, gpu, julia

I'm stuck in getting Julia to run on Ubuntu 16.04 on a server having GPUs. Basically we want to utilise power of GPUs. 
We're using Docker image to host Julia, it's pulled from nvidia-cuda, the docker image is building successfully, but when I run julia with any switch e.g. julia -v or just julia, I'm getting error ERROR: Unable to find compatible target in system image. I tried finding hints online but no luck, hence posting question here. 
After building docker image, I'm running using **docker run** command by mounting some shared folders, it's coming up successfully, but Julia doesn't seem to work. Please let me know what wrong am I doing here.
Following is Dockerfile code

```
    FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04
MAINTAINER comafire <comafire@gmail.com>

# Bash
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

USER root

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
apt-utils \
&& apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Lang
ARG locale="en_US.UTF-8"
ENV LOCALE ${locale}
RUN echo "LOCALE: $LOCALE"
RUN if [[ $LOCALE = *en* ]] \
; then \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
locales language-pack-en \
; else \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
locales language-pack-en \
; fi
RUN echo "$LOCALE UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
ENV LC_ALL ${LOCALE}
ENV LANG ${LOCALE}
ENV LANGUAGE ${LOCALE}
ENV LC_MESSAGES POSIX

# Common
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
build-essential vim curl wget git cmake bzip2 sudo unzip net-tools \
libffi-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev llvm \
libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
software-properties-common libjpeg-dev libpng-dev ncurses-dev imagemagick \
libgraphicsmagick1-dev libzmq-dev gfortran gnuplot gnuplot-x11 libsdl2-dev \
openssh-client htop iputils-ping

# Python2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv python-software-properties
RUN pip2 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip2 install --cache-dir /tmp/pip2 --upgrade setuptools wheel

# Python3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-virtualenv python3-software-properties
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --cache-dir /tmp/pip3 --upgrade setuptools wheel

# Julia
ENV JULIA_VERSION 1.0.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libatomic1 python gfortran perl wget m4 cmake pkg-config
RUN cd /usr/local && git clone git://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git && cd julia && git checkout v${JULIA_VERSION}
#RUN make -C deps distclean-llvm && make
RUN cd /usr/local/julia && make -j4
RUN sudo ln -s /usr/local/julia/usr/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
RUN /usr/local/julia/usr/bin/julia -v
RUN ls -al /usr/local/bin
RUN julia -v
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY packages.jl ./
RUN julia packages.jl
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing `RUN julia` is `julia` already in your `$PATH`? Try executing julia directly, for example:

```
RUN chmod +x /path/to/julia
RUN /path/to/julia
```

Comment: Hi @user172056,
That wasn't the issue. I added target cpu part in the make statement as shown below and the error disappeared. However the main issue still persists i.e. CUDAnative package doesn't seem to get installed correctly.

RUN make all -j$(nproc) \
        MARCH=x86-64 \
        JULIA_CPU_TARGET=x86-64 && \
    rm -rf deps/scratch deps/srccache usr-staging